# React Native - Undefined Is Not An Object(Evaluating 'Items.Length')

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

i can not sort out the issues- related to SectionList - React-native component.

This is my Data Structure:

```
[
  {
    id: 'newKey1',
    image: '',
    title: 'Men Clothing',
    subCategory: [
      {
        id: 'key1',
        displayName: 'value1',
        image: '',
      },
      {
        id: 'key2',
        displayName: 'value2',
        image: '',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'newKey2',
    image: '',
    title: 'Women Clothing',
    subCategory: [
      {
        id: 'key1',
        displayName: 'value1',
        image: '',
      },
      {
        id: 'key2',
        displayName: 'value2',
        image: '',
      },
      {
        id: 'key3',
        displayName: 'value3',
        image: '',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Im trying to implement SectionList, where `data` is the above const value passed.

```
 return (
<View style={styles(theme).container}>
        <AdBanner />
        <SectionList sections={data} />
      </View>
);
```

but im getting an error: **Undefined Is Not An Object(Evaluating 'Items.Length')**

please kindly help and share possible solution for it
thank you

Answer (score 13):

It turns out the SectionLists requires a sections prop that takes an array of objects that REQUIRE a data prop, which is an array. This is easy to miss in the docs.

```
const DATA = [{
title: "Cake"
data : ["Some string", "Some other string"]
}];

<SectionList
  sections={DATA}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs your data must be in the form `Array<Section>`, where `Section` includes a `Data` Array property.

More info: https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist#section

Answer (score 0):

@Bryson Kruk's answer is right. But i was getting the same error even after following the necessary steps, i.e, having data in this format;

```
const DATA = [{
title: "Some Title"
data : ["Some string", "Some other string"]
}];
```

And `SectionList` had the prop `sections`;

```
<SectionList
  sections={DATA}
/>
```

But Another point to be noted here is that, the value of data (present inside the DATA) must be a list. What i mean is, say you are trying to get the data on some calculations and sometimes the calculated value maybe `null` or any other thing other than a list. At that time it also gives such errors.

So to get rid of such errors, we should set its value as empty list when we have no data instead of setting it to `null` or any other value.

Comment: The "must be a string" requirement is not true, or at least is no longer true (ReactNative 0.63.4).  The elements in my data arrays are objects and it's working fine.

Comment: @ChrisBartley i am sorry. That was a typo. What i mean't to say is that we shouldn't have data as null. It should be a list either empty when we have no data or with some elements.